# Maps vs Concrete classes

Tags: mule

In Mule, when I talk to an external web service or API I typically just convert the response to a Map to work with the values.

Is this the correct approach? Is there a rule/best practice when to convert to a map vs converting to a concrete class using Jaxb or something?

If I am building an API in Mule, i create my response object DTOs as concrete class say User.class etc. But when I'm consuming other services or APIs I tend to just convert to a Map. I guess the downside here is knowing the structure of the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is the best as it abides to the [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

Indeed, you want your applications to be:

- strict with the data they produce, and you reach this strictness by using response DTOs,
- lax with the data they consume, and you reach that goal too by using maps for dealing with remote responses.

Comment: Thanks,  Yes, I am using response DTOs that I serialize to json for my API responses, but just use maps when consuming remote services downstream.